# Relationship/independence between 2 binary varibales

Tags: categorical-data, independence

I got a dataset in Excel with 2 dichotomous variables: trained (1 or 0), part-time (1 or 0).
The question asks if whether there is a relationship between those who have been trained and whether they are part-time rather than permanent employees? It also says that it requires a formal test in terms of whether employment type and "trained" are independent variables.

So, I filter the column "trained" to have individuals with "1" only 
Then, I run a regression analysis to see if the coefficients are significant

Do I also need to filter for the part-time column before running the regression?

I am not sure if that is the correct way to answer this question? Or it is trying to ask me to do the test based on the probability function? 
$P(A) P(B) = P(A \cap B)$. 
If so, how can I handle this in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The independence between two binary variables can be studied statistically using [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test), alternatively, it's common to use the [chi-square test for independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data).

---

Note that regression analysis is a different type of approach. There are several types of regression, to name two: linear regression deals with continuous variables (that is not the case here); and logistic regression deals with a dichotomous dependent variable (like here) but it is more complex than doing a Fisher test or a qui-square test.

---

Your equation is the probabilistic way of studying exactly if there is independence. In a $2\times2$ table, you may check for independence by checking if
$$
P(tr=1, pt=1) = P(tr=1) P(pt=1)
$$
where $tr$ stands for training and $pt$ stands for part-time.
However, this approach is different from statistical hypothesis testing that deals with sample data. The way your question is worded leads me to think that statistical testing is the correct approach in this case.